# Is there a find algorithm for Google Protocol Buffers (Protobuf)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, find, protocol-buffers

Is there a find algorithm for Google Protobuf array objects?

eg, if I have a protobuf with a repeated field such as

```
message MyProto {
    repeated int32 intArray = 1;
}
```

how can I find a particular integer value in `intArray`?

There is an `erase` method which is generated for repeated fields, but there doesn't appear to be any similar method for `find`.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no `find` member function generated for C++ protobuf objects, stl like `begin` and `end` functions are available, which means `std::find` from `#include <algorithm>` can be used.

```
if(find(intarray.cbegin(), intarray.cend(), value) != intarray.cend())
{
    // found
}
```